# How to remove a list of elements from a list?

Tags: python, list

Suppose there are lists `A` and `B`:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
B = [2, 4, 6]
```

I want to modify `A` so it becomes

```
A = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I won't want use `remove`, as `A` can have 10k numbers

Comment: Is `A` always sorted?

Comment: sorted or not are both fine

Comment: Just to remove the elements in B from A.

Comment: Are you sure that `remove` is too slow?

Comment: Look into tree data structures instead of lists.

Comment: B can have 1 million numbers, what to do then

Comment: Don't you think that that information might have been worth mentioning in your question?

Comment: By the way, you're getting downvoted because you have not shown even minimal effort to solve the problem yourself. StackOverflow is for helping out, not for giving you complete solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
A = [x for x in A if x not in B]
```

Comment: @WasifHasan But this should have the same complexity as repeated calls of `remove`?

Comment: @Thomas the time complexity is bad, I cannot provide better solutions except `set()` which have been covered

Comment: If `A` is sorted you could use binary search which gets you from O(n·m) to O(logn·m) - but sets would still be faster :) But then again - sets don't do exactly the same thing as lists as you have demonstrated in your comment to the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your use case allows it; you can use `set` operations, which are super efficient:

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> B = [2, 4, 6]
>>> A = list(set(A) - set(B))
>>> A
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Note that this will not keep `A` in the same order and will remove all duplicates from it.

A <strike>slower</strike> *faster* way, <strike>but</strike> and one that preserves duplicates in `A`, and maintains its order, is to use a list comprehension. But then it's critical that you **first** convert `B` to a `set` to make the `in` operation as fast as possible:

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> B = [2, 4, 6]
>>> set_b = set(B)
>>> A = [n for n in A if n not in set_b]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

**EDIT**: The list comprehension with the `set` lookup is surprisingly actually the faster solution:

```
$ python3 -m timeit --number=1000 --setup='import random; A = random.sample(range(10 ** 6), 10 ** 5); B = random.sample(range(10 ** 6), 10 ** 4)' 'list(set(A) - set(B))'
1000 loops, best of 5: 18.7 msec per loop
```

```
$ python3 -m timeit --number=1000 --setup='import random; A = random.sample(range(10 ** 6), 10 ** 5); B = random.sample(range(10 ** 6), 10 ** 4)' 'set_b = set(B); [n for n in A if n not in set_b]'
1000 loops, best of 5: 11.8 msec per loop
```

Comment: But has side effects too, removal of duplicate elements

Comment: @WasifHasan But this seems to be in line with the questions? It's unclear.

Comment: @Thomas consider an example `set([1,2,1])-set([2])`, Here the expected output should be `{1,1}` but it will remove duplicates so return `{1}` so isn't it incorrect?

Comment: thanks! i tried, it is very efficient and good to use thanks

Comment: @WasifHasan It might be that removing duplicates is fine.

Comment: @WasifHasan - oh, I see. You're correct, of course. However, in your comment you said "removal of duplicate elements", this is about the duplicate elements that should *remain* in `A`.

Comment: @ZMike If this answers your question, please tick the answer as "accepted".

Comment: This is not too surprising, given that the O-complexity is the same for both variants but you save the conversion between set and list for A.